# MongoDB - Grant permission over one collection that exists on all databases

Tags: mongodb, permissions, mongodb-3.4

I have several databases on my MongoDB, all of them have or will have a collection called `_schema`. Currently, I'm granting permissions like this:

```
db.grantRolesToUser("userA",[
  {"role": "readWrite", "db" : "databaseA", "collection": "_schema"}
]);
db.grantRolesToUser("userA",[
  {"role": "readWrite", "db" : "databaseB", "collection": "_schema"}
]);
.
.
.
db.grantRolesToUser("userA",[
  {"role": "readWrite", "db" : "databaseZ", "collection": "_schema"}
]);
```

Is there a way to grant `readWrite` for that particular collection on all databases without granting on each db individually?

(I want the `write` permission just for that collection, others will be just `read`)

Comment: Maybe you can create a custom role using [createRole](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/method/db.createRole/), and assign it to related users. MongoDB v3.4 is quite old, and the present version is v5.

Comment: @prasad_ thanks! in that case, the `resource` would be `{ cluster : true }` ?

Comment: Should  be `resource: { db: "", collection: "_schema" }`, see [Specify Collections Across Databases as Resource](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/resource-document/#specify-collections-across-databases-as-resource)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thank you!